# SSHd restriction per user basis

Tags: ssh

I need to restrict certain user(s) so that they can only SSH in using ssh keys and other users can login using key or password.

an example:

i'd like for root user to be able to login remotely (through sshd) using key, so no password would be accepted (even if password is right)

and for other users (everyone on the system) they can log in using key and/or password

how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to set `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` such that:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

just for extra security and to avoid having the root password locked (it would only allow root to log in using a key)

I would instead use `AllowGroups` instead of `AllowUser`, as for me it would be more convenient to add users to a group rather than to `sshd_config` but that could depend on your personal preferences.

Answer (score 22):

I think what you want is "Match User". You use it to match a username, then indent a series of config settings that apply specifically to that user.

```
Match User Joe
  PasswordAuthentication no

Match User Jane
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I use this to set up chroot SFTP-only access sometimes for clients.

Comment: Note that not all settings can be written in the `Match` block. See `man 5 sshd_config` for the detail.

Answer (score 2):

Set up ssh as follows:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

AllowUsers username1 username2 username3
```

Restart SSH

Then provide the keys to those who you would like to avoid using passwords.

ssh-keygen is used to generate that key pair for you. Here is a session where your own personal private/public key pair is created:

```
#ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The command ssh-keygen -t rsa initiated the creation of the key pair.

I didn't enter a passphrase for my setup (Enter key was pressed instead).

The private key was saved in .ssh/id_rsa. This file is read-only and only for you. No one else must see the content of that file, as it is used to decrypt all correspondence encrypted with the public key.

The public key is save in .ssh/id_rsa.pub.

Its content is then copied in file .ssh/authorized_keys of the system you wish to SSH to without being prompted for a password.

```
#scp id_rsa.pub remote system:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Finally lock the account (Key authentication will still be possible.)

```
# passwd -l username1
```

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for. let's say i want root to be logged in using keys only and other users can be logged with key or password

Comment: then don't lock the account with passwd -l username1

Answer (score 0):

All the above are great and work and if I may be allowed to tie it up a little.  I use a standard `sshd_config` across a large number of servers and flavours making the configuration a deliberate thought processes and this is what I use.

My use case:

- Root access is restricted to key only from 2 specific IP's
- Automation users (eg ansible) are restricted to key only from specific servers (eg RunDeck, Jenkins, etc)
- Application users may not login at all using ssh
- Admins and users may use key or password

Firstly, I primarily use `Allow_Groups`, easier to manage across multiple boxes with a pleothora of different users.  For users common to all boxes (eg automation or monitoring), `allow_Users` also works well but I still prefer using groups.

Now down to the actual configs `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

First off, all only specific group (or users) SSH access:

```
AllowGroups sshusr
```

This essentially means the users need to be a member of the `sshusr` group in order to be able to use SSH.  To prevent application users gaining ssh access, simply make sure they are **not** a member of the `sshusr` group.  **NOTE:** This includes root so you need to add `root` to the `sshusr` group!

For root access via key only use:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

For restricting groups to use key-only authentication :

```
Match Group ansible,monitor
  PasswordAuthentication no
```

As a default, I turn off things like `port forwarding` and `X11 forwarding` etc but for specific groups you may want to turn it on and allow password authentication (usually `on` by default but for secure environments you may want to turn it `off` to make keys the default)

```
Match Group sysadmin,dbadmin
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  PermitTunnel yes
  X11Forwarding yes
```

Then you have the special cases like `sftp` only users:

```
Match Group sftp
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  PermitTTY no
  MaxSessions 5
```

Now for restricting the keys to allow access from specific IP's only.  This works for FQDN's as well but I have not used it here.  In the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file prepend the `from=` restriction to the applicable key(s)

```
from="10.1.1.1,10.2.2.2,10.3.3.0/24" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NTheRestOfMyKeyxyz
```

That will allow the key to be used from those specific IP's only.

I trust this helps you and potentially many others.